# Loading multidigital characters into array from file

Tags: arrays, file, assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm trying to load numbers from txt file into array in 8086.
I did it for one digit numbers, but I don't know how to do it when there's more than one.

My txt file looks like this:

```
1:4
2:3
5:10
```

And I should load to array values, which are after the `':'`.

My code looks like this:

```
    org 100h


;load text file (coin stock) 
load:
mov dx, offset file ; address of file to dx
mov al,0 ; open file (read-only)
mov ah,3dh
int 21h ; call the interupt 

jc terminate ; if error occurs, terminate program

mov bx,ax ; 
mov cx,1 ; read one character at a time  
mov di, 0 


putInArray: 
lea dx, BUF
mov ah,3fh ; 
int 21h
CMP AX, 0 ; 
JZ terminate ; 

mov al, BUF
cmp BUF, 3Ah  ; compare if character is equal to ":"
JNE putInArray   ; if not, jump back    
array:
lea dx, BUF   ; if yes: take next character
mov ah,3fh ; 
int 21h
CMP AX, 0 ; 
JZ terminate   

cmp BUF, 13d
JE putInArray       


mov al, BUF   ;move character to AL
mov coinStock[di], al ; put character into array coinStock
inc di   

jmp array ; repeat if not end of file. 

terminate:
mov ah, 0 ; wait for any key...
int 16h
ret

    file db "c:\coinstock.txt", 0
    BUF db ?
    coinStock db 3 dup(?)     
END
```

Comment: Have you attempted to step through your code with a debugger to see what might be wrong?

Comment: Yes, but I know what is wrong :), there are three options: 1) I have only '1' instead of 10 on the 3rd position of array 2) I have '0' instead of 10 3) I have '1' on the 3rd position and '0' on the 4rd position (if I have a bigger array of course) - I don't know how to put more than 1 digital number into array

Comment: You can convert the numbers into bytes or words and store it in an array of bytes or words or you can copy the ASCII characters and create an array of pointers (offsets) to the addresses of the numbers.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know how to convert numbers from file into bytes/words, because my program takes 1 char at the time and put it into an array, so I don't know how to rewrite it in that way that it will be taking all numbers until the end of the line and put them as one number into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your program puts *single characters* in the array but with multidigital numbers this is no longer possible. You have to put the numerical value (limited to 1 byte) in the array.

```
mov al, 0  
mov coinStock[di], al ;Initial content
array:
lea dx, BUF           ;if yes: take next character
mov ah,3fh
int 21h
CMP AX, 0
JZ  terminate
cmp BUF, 13d
JE  EndOfLine         ;(putInArray)
mov al, coinStock[di]
mov ah, 10
mul ah
mov coinStock[di], al
mov al, BUF           ;move character to AL
sub al, 48            ;From character to number
add coinStock[di], al ;Add character into array coinStock
jmp array             ;repeat if not end of file.
EndOfLine:
inc di
jmp putInArray
```

Comment: Thank You very much, thats exactly what I needed!